# android: How to get the ID of a textview when clicked?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have an activity that queries from sqllite and display the output to xml

this is part of the activity

```
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id) ).setText( listItem.getId()+"");
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name) ).setText( listItem.getName() );
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_age) ).setText( listItem.getAge()+"" );
```

and this is the xml:

```
<TableLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/tv_age" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name">
  <TableRow 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/tv_age" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TableLayout01"   
   android:id="@+id/TableRow01">
   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="10dip" 
    android:layout_height="30dip"     
    android:id="@+id/tv_id" 
    android:text=""     
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
   </TextView>
   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="100dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" android:id="@+id/tv_name" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_id" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px">
   </TextView>
   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" android:id="@+id/tv_age" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px">
   </TextView>
  </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Now this works fine.  It displays the resulting query.  Now, I want to create another activity which responds to the long press or just one touch when the query is displayed.  How can I get the ID of the pressed textview so I can use it for the other activity?

many thanks for your help.

Comment: isn't it view.getId() ?

Answer (score 13):

**Do like this instead:**

```
TextView tvId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
tvId.setText( listItem.getId()+"");
tvId.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then in the `onClickEvent` you get the id of the text view like "apps" write, with the `getId()` method.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the String of the id you can use the following method:

```
String name = getIDName(MyTextView, R.id.class);

public static String getIDName(View view, Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {

        Integer id = view.getId();
        Field[] ids = clazz.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            Object val = ids[i].get(null);
            if (val != null && val instanceof Integer
                    && ((Integer) val).intValue() == id.intValue()) {
                return ids[i].getName();
            }
        }

        return "";

    }
```